# Is baffle-step compensation obsolete because of room correction?

Tags: speakers, signal-processing, loudspeakers

When installing speakers in or on wall, are baffle-step correction circuits now unnecessary? Would there be any benefit to continuing designing speakers to compensate in the crossover, or is it sufficient to remove it from the signal before amplification?